# Why is there an apostrophe after years

Tags: sentence-meaning, apostrophe

I'm reading an wikipedia article:

> (...) was sentenced to five years' probation and one year in the House of Correction (...)

Why `five years'` has an apostrophe? What does that sentence mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English genitive (-'s for singular nouns, -' used on plural nouns; more commonly known as the **possessive**) can be used in some expressions of time to associate something with the length of time.

> Hundred Years' War
>   one week's notice
>   a good night's sleep
>   a hard day's work

In your case, the genitive is denoting that the probation was five years **in duration**, with a similar construction to "Hundred Years' War" and "Seven Years' War" (those are actual names of wars). "One week's notice" is notice given **during the week before** something happens.